# Jquery validation plugin addMethod doesn't work

Tags: jquery, validation

First of all, I'm really sorry if I'm asking the same question but I've done all the research on the site and gone through all the similar question but still haven't been able to fix my problem.

I try to use a simple form validation plugin with JQuery, I have some default text in the filed and I try to add a custom method to return false when the user doesn't enter first and last name in the fields. As both the fields have a default text in them the validation returns true so it doesn't display the error message next to the first and last name. I'm quite sure I'm making a very simple mistake but still...

I would really appreciate any help and once again really sorry for asking the similar question!

here is the link of my form:

http://titan.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~ztoth01/JQuery/contactform_jq.html

Comment: Can you post your code here? Link only references could be broken.

Comment: This seems to work, at least the method is being called as you can see in the `console` however I think you're referencing `defaultValue` wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/He65T/